# ディレクトリ内の、パスを含まないファイル名だけを ListBox に表示したい

Tags: c#

`Button` をクリックするとディレクトリを選択するダイアログを表示し、選択したディレクトリに存在する txt ファイルを `ListBox` に表示させようと思いました。コードを実行し、無事に指定したディレクトリに存在する txt ファイルを `ListBox` に表示することはできましたが、 `ListBox` に表示されたデータは、`C:\`からはじまる絶対パス付きで表示されています。

以下が書いたコードの一部になります。

```
 var Dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
 var Result = Dialog.ShowDialog();
 if (Result == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
 {
     var Directory = Dialog.FileName;
     string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory, "*.txt");
     listBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
 }
```

これを実行すると `ListBox` にパス付きでファイル名が表示されます。どうにか `ファイル名.txt` のみを表示させたいのですが、うまくいっていません。調べてみたところ、 `GetFileName`を使う方法があるようですが、どうもうまくいきません。

何か方法がありましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか？

※ ちなみにディレクトリの選択するダイアログには、 Windows API CodePack を使用しています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dialog.FileName);
listBox1.DataSource = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

こんな方法もあります。listBox1にはFileInfo配列を渡し、FileInfoクラスのNameプロパティを画面に表示するように指示できます。この場合、listBox1.SelectedItemプロパティはFileInfoインスタンスを指すようになるので、その後の処理が楽になります。
なお、変数名は先頭を小文字にしましょう。（listBox1もその命名規則に従っています。）

Comment: こちらの方法ではワイルドカードを使用して特定の拡張子のファイルだけを表示させることはできないのでしょうか？

Comment: すいません。
つい先ほどのコメントは自己解決しました。
GetFilesで指定できましたね。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

ディレクトリ名が取れているのであれば、DirectoryInfoのGetFilesを呼べば、FileInfoの配列が取得できるので、そこからNameを取ればファイル名が取得できます。

ディレクトリ名がわかっているのであれば以下の様にできます。

```
var directory = "c:\\";
var x = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory);
var p = x.GetFiles("*.txt").Select( fileinfo => fileinfo.Name);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(p.ToArray());
```

フルパスが欲しい場合は、fileinfoのFullNameを取得すればフルパスも取得できます。

なお、selectで抽出せずListBoxに設定しても表示は同じ様にファイル名のみですが、
ListBoxに格納されているオブジェクトはFileInfoになります。

```
var directory = "c:\\";
var x = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(x.GetFiles("*.txt"));

// 注意：ファイルが見つかっていない場合はエラーになります。
var obj = (System.IO.FileInfo)listBox1.Items[0];
MessageBox.Show(obj.FullName);
```

後で選択されたアイテムのファイル情報を再利用したい場合など、状況によってはそのままListBoxに設定してしまう方が便利な場合もありますので、うまく使い分けてください。

Answer (score 1):

ＬＩＮＱを使って以下のように修正すればいいかと思います。

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory, "*.txt").Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Linqを使用する場合、Directory.EnumerateFilesを使うと効率的です。
ListBox.AddRangeは、配列を受け取るため、ToArrayでファイル名の一覧の配列を生成します。

```
listbox.AddRange( 
  Directory.EnumerateFiles( @"c:\files" , "*.txt" )
      .Select( Path.GetFileName ) // ファイルパスからファイル名を抽出
      .ToArray()                  // 配列に変換
);
```

Comment: コードブロックとして表示されるようにマークアップを編集しました: インデントを4つ入れるとコードブロックになります。(編集フォームの上にある `{}` ボタンでもok)